# SMTPAuthenticationError on Heroku

Tags: python, django

I am trying to request a reset password from a system deployed on heroku but i get this error.

SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/
(534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs\n5.7.14 i1cE5v2I-3UUFLl6jQMnBfbcvZuRiGo_q9k1T5h2XgMGxtKYIJ0sIPE9Jr6zW1X78xQM3\n5.7.14 Py7mrOXSPkPG01upxjbZRi68aLrKIbvG_4uHrli9l7ZVmFnr8CxRNb9JUDGVcm8M>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 k188sm1479373qkd.98 - gsmtp')

I have set all these settings and they seem to be okay but i still get the same error. Kindly help

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your application is probably fine, but the issue is with Google, that is preventing your login as it is a potentially suspicious activity. You may have received a mail from Google telling you that a suspicious activity has happened.

To solve this problem, you have to change your Google's security settings and create an app password so you can login from your application:

1. Using a browser, login to your Gmail account
2. Go to "Manage your account"
3. Go to "Security"
4. In "Signing to Google" section, click on "App passwords"
5. Enter your password
6. In "Select the app and device you want to generate the app password for.", select Other, name it anyway you want and click "Generate"
7. Use this password in Django instead of your regular password.